# How do you read the properties of a file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, properties

I am currently working on two programs and both are still in the planning phase but I have one question that I need to answer before I finish planning. Is there anyway to pull a file in and read the properties? 
Basically what I want to do is be able to read the properties of image files and pull out the resolution, file size, date taken, and all that. And then do the same with music files (artist, album, length, so on). The closest I've found is a 6 year old project to pull the EXIF information out of images at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exifextractor.aspx . 
I'd be thrilled if there is one method to pull properties out of both kinds of file types. But I'll also be happy with two separate ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a .NET way to access [media metadata properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384862.aspx)?

Comment: Yes. That looks like everything I would need.

Answer (score 3):

Including the one you found, there's also a good one hosted on Google Code named [ExifLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/exiflibrary/).

**Edit:** Found another one [here](http://renaud91.free.fr/MetaDataExtractor/) based on [Drew Noakes Java MetaData Extractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I downloaded the dll and will start toying with it. But you are an evil evil person. I had no idea there was a code.google.com . Now I will get even less sleep.

Comment: Don't feel bad.  StackOverflow has become my current addiction.

Comment: @brian: There's also [SourceForge](http://sf.net), [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net), [GitHub](http://github.com), [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com)